# SQLite-Manager on Firefox and Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have written a small test application using SQLite with Python 3.3:

```
import sqlite3

MDB = sqlite3.connect('D:\MDB.db')              # create the db object
cursor = MDB.cursor()                           # assign a cursor

 cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS section (
                   Code        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                   Description TEXT )
                ''')

 cursor.execute('''DELETE FROM section''')      # delete contents for reruns

 cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO section
                   (Description)
                   VALUES (?)
                ''', ('Abdul, Paula',))

 cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO section
                   (Description)
                   VALUES (?)
                ''', ('ABWH',))


print('Results:\n')
cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM section''')
selection = cursor.fetchall()
for row in selection:
    print('\t', row)
```

The SELECT statement shows the results expected (seeming to indicate that the row exists), but if I connect to the database with SQLite-Manager, the table exists but is empty, and if I try the same query with another script connected to the database, nothing is returned. Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not saving changes (calling `MDB.commit`).